# git log results are different than git.api results

Tags: git, github, github-api

When I run the command "git log -m --name-only" on git. I came up with 2 results having the same commit-sha.[image]

When I use Github API for the same commit the result is like this;[image]

Why do I get the second result having the same commit sha(from e327....) on git? What does the second result means?

Comment: I think it is showing you the same revision but showing differences from the 2 parents.

Comment: Okay, but I dont get why github api only considers one parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more important question here is why you would *expect* these to be the same.

Remember that `git log` is a method of querying reality—asking what's in the Git databases—by formulating some specific set of questions and getting answers.  Meanwhile, GitHub's APIs are also methods of querying reality by asking specific questions to get specific answers, but the GitHub API questions are *different*.  They're at most *related to* some of the questions you can ask with `git log`.  Since you're asking different questions, you'll get different answers, and you should expect that.  If you were going out on a date with your SO or spouse, you presumably would not expect to get the *same* answer to "what time will we have our date" and "what color clothing will you wear on our date".

In any case, `git log -m` specifically directs the `git log` command to *split* a merge commit into two or more virtual commits.  An actual merge commit has, by definition, 2 or more parents.  If the merge commit has two parents, `git log -m` makes `git log` *display* that merge commit twice, with each display handled as if it were a single-parent commit with only one of those two parents.

The reason to do this is because `git log` can show a *diff* of a commit against its (single) parent.  The `git log` command *does not* show any diff of a merge commit against its multiple parents,<sup>1</sup> but adding `-m` to `git log` makes it pretend that merge commit M, with the two parents P1 and P2, was really commit M-from-P1, with parent P1, and M-from-P2, with parent P2.  That enables its diff-showing code.

The GitHub API you invoked does not show a diff in the same way as the `git log` command, and hence does not have any reason to have an equivalent to the `-m` option.  Instead, it appears to use the combined-diff code (see footnote 1) or some variant thereof.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git log` command can also be told to produce a *combined diff*.  A combined diff is very different from two individual diffs.  The options for this are `-c` and `--cc`; the two produce somewhat different output.  See [the Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_diff_format_for_merges) for details.